# SQL to show status for both id and next_id in a single row

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Can someone help me on below please:
I tried the below SQL

```
select 
    CUSTOMER,
    ID as Current_ID, 
    lead(ID) over (partition by ID order by CUSTOMER, ID) as Next_ID,
    STATUS, 
    START_DATE, 
    END_DATE
From Source_Table
```

My table has values like below
[image: Source table data]

The expected outcome should be
[image: Expected Outcome]

Comment: What have you tried do far? can there be only two records per customer?

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: Add some more sample data, e.g. customers with only 1 row, and 3 rows, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Added some more sample data.. Thanks Guys

Comment: It's not clear how your expected result should be derived from your source data. Why is `CURRENT_ID` for Peter 20 and not 10 or 30? It's not because today is in the range of `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`, so we have no way to know why this record is the one being returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
create table #Source_Table
(
    CUSTOMER varchar(20),
    ID int,
    [STATUS] varchar(20),
    [START_DATE] date,
    END_DATE date
)

insert into #Source_Table values
('John',10,'Delivered','2022-04-01','2023-03-31'),
('John',20,'Requested','2023-04-01','2024-03-31'),
('Martin',10,'Delivered','2023-05-01','2023-08-31'),
('Peter',10,'Delivered','2023-04-03','2023-06-30'),
('Peter',20,'Delivered','2023-07-01','2023-08-31'),
('Peter',30,'Requested','2023-09-01','2023-03-31')
```

This query will return every record, with the next ID and STATUS where applicable:

```
select
    CUSTOMER,
    ID as CURRENT_ID,
    [STATUS] as CURRENT_ID_STATUS,
    lead(ID) over (partition by CUSTOMER order by ID) as NEXT_ID,
    lead([STATUS]) over (partition by CUSTOMER order by ID) as NEXT_ID_STATUS,
    [START_DATE],
    END_DATE
from #Source_Table
```

Results:

| CUSTOMER | CURRENT_ID | CURRENT_ID_STATUS | NEXT_ID | NEXT_ID_STATUS | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | Delivered | 20 | Requested | 01/04/2022 | 31/03/2023 |
| John | 20 | Requested | NULL | NULL | 01/04/2023 | 31/03/2024 |
| Martin | 10 | Delivered | NULL | NULL | 01/05/2023 | 31/08/2023 |
| Peter | 10 | Delivered | 20 | Delivered | 03/04/2023 | 30/06/2023 |
| Peter | 20 | Delivered | 30 | Requested | 01/07/2023 | 31/08/2023 |
| Peter | 30 | Requested | NULL | NULL | 01/09/2023 | 31/03/2023 |

It seems from your expected output that you then want to filter this in some way, but without you explaining the criteria for that filtering, I don't think anyone can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer - if you found it helpful then please consider upvoting it as well. Have a great day.